# Mysql - result the data's with or with out available in DB

Tags: java, mysql

This is my sql query to sum the error count in DB. What made the problem below is, when I check the available data in this, it retrieve the actual and correct data given, if I'm giving any wrong (that is unavailable data in table) input it gives nothing that is it doesn't throw any output screen:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(ieb.errortype_id='1',1,0)) AS Total_Critical,
  SUM(IF(ieb.errortype_id='2',1,0)) AS Total_Non_critical,
  u.emp_id,
  u.emp_name 
FROM 
  issueerror_empmap iem,
  issueerror_body ieb, 
  USER u, 
  issueerror_type iet 
WHERE 
  ieb.chapter_id = '424262' AND 
  iem.chapter_errorid=ieb.chapter_errorid AND 
  iem.emp_id = u.emp_id AND 
  u.emp_id = '693' AND 
  ieb.errortype_id=iet.errortype_id 
GROUP BY 
  iem.emp_id,
  u.emp_name 
ORDER BY 
  iem.emp_id
```

Can any one please suggest me how to build this query to retrieve the data if available and display the output as null if the input data not available in a table.

For producing the output for the above query is (if data available in a table):

```
Total_Critical   Total_Non_Critical  emp_id  emp_name
 4                 10                   xxx     xxx
```

For producing the output for the above query is (if data not available in a table):

```
Total_Critical   Total_Non_Critical  emp_id  emp_name
```

I am expecting the emp_id and emp_name with the error count as null or zeroes.

Comment: In future, could you make an attempt to format queries for readability?  I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

how about this query?

```
select
sum (Total_Critical) as Total_Critical,
sum(Total_Non_critical) as Total_Non_critical,
emp_id,
emp_name from 
(
(SELECT 
  SUM(IF(ieb.errortype_id='1',1,0)) AS Total_Critical,
  SUM(IF(ieb.errortype_id='2',1,0)) AS Total_Non_critical,
  u.emp_id,
  u.emp_name 
FROM 
  issueerror_empmap iem,
  issueerror_body ieb, 
  USER u, 
  issueerror_type iet 
WHERE 
  ieb.chapter_id = '424262' AND 
  iem.chapter_errorid=ieb.chapter_errorid AND 
  iem.emp_id = u.emp_id AND 
  u.emp_id = '693' AND 
  ieb.errortype_id=iet.errortype_id 
GROUP BY 
  iem.emp_id,
  u.emp_name 
ORDER BY 
  iem.emp_id ) 
) UNION ALL (
 select 0,0,null, null
)
) as tbl1
```